# Array List in XPages how to parse

Tags: arrays, xpages

I have some values in array like this below (arr1);
I need to make a kind of unique arrayList which has to collect and make a new list with values before **"~"** 
If the value before the "~" is in the new list, the value after "~" has to append into existing value of array.

```
var arr1:Array = new Array();
arr1[0] = "test 1 ~ 781.102";
arr1[1] = "test 2 ~ 981.112";
arr1[2] = "test 2 ~ 191.222";
arr1[3] = "~ 431.332";
arr1[4] = "test 1 ~ 121.332";
arr1[5] = "test 3 ~ 121.442";
arr1[6] = "test 3 ~ 201.552";
```

New List should be this...

```
 var nArr:Array = new Array();
    nArr[0]= "test 1 - (781.102,121.332)";
    nArr[1]= "test 2 - (981.112,191.222)";
    nArr[2]= "test 3 - (121.442,201.552)";
    nArr[3]= "undefined - (431.332)";
```

Comment: This is not a "please write my code"- community. Show what you tried, and tell us why you failed. Show us code, that did not work, and we will help. But nobody here will write code for you...

Comment: Thank you. I am a new one in Javascript. 
I do not want anybody to write my code. I do not know what to try that's why I asked.  What i need is just a logical explanation.

Comment: Just redirect me to place where to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.split("~")](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to separate substrings divided by `~`. The result is an array.

Use a JavaScript [object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) with keys and values. The key is "test 1", "test 2", ... and the value is a JavaScript [array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). Add for every element of arr1 the number to array for the given key.

Finally, create an array from your object and convert the array values into "( ..., ...)"

Your code would look like this:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) { 
    var keyAndValue = arr1[i].split("~");
    var key = keyAndValue[0].trim();
    var value = keyAndValue[1].trim();
    var array = [];
    if (key in obj) {
        array = obj[key];
    } 
    array.push(value);
    obj[key] = array;
}
var nArr = [];
for (key in obj) {
    nArr.push(key + " - (" + obj[key].toString() + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're using are not ArrayLists, they're Arrays.

To avoid reinventing a wheel, search the web for java.util.ArrayList if you want best practice on how to manipulate an ArrayList.

The best advice is to use Java constructs rather than SSJS Arrays. They are documented more widely on the web (because they're used beyond just XPages) and will get you used to handling these kinds of things in Java business logic in the future. Look at Lists and Sets and Maps.

What you're actually wanting is not a unique list, it's a Map of unique values (to the left of a tilde) followed by a concatenated string of entries that use that key.

Comment: I do not have java experince :( 
I am new one here.. I mean JavaScript and XPages

Comment: You don't need java experience to use java objects inside of XPages ServerSide JavaScript. As Paul suggests that's probably your best bet.  I have a video that might help you start using Java Object inside SSJS.  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/07/11/notesin9-ee-009-using-java-hashmaps-and-treemaps-with-xpages/

Comment: You don't need to use Java classes. JavaScript's objects and arrays give you the functionality you are looking for.